# Umbraco, call an action in custon Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, umbraco

i need to know how call an action in custom Api Controller. For exemple in this official guide there is a controller called: "BlogsCommentController". Have an action "GetComments"... https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core

In other part of code, how is the service or other methods, to call this action that have this url: "Umbraco/Api/BlogComments/GetComments" and return a list of comments?

I would like to know how to make a call to a controller (Api Controller), more precisely its action to return the requested values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you would have a two port application.  Port 1 is a HTTP connection from client to server where the controller is in the server. Port 2 is a connection from the server to the database and in this case you are using entity.  The controller when it receives a HTTP request from the client will forward the request (query) to the database.  The database will then return the data to the controller which is then sent to the client in the HTTP Response.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but i didn't know how service use Umbraco to call Api Controller and get value by specific Action.

Comment: Did you see following : https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/code/umbraco-services

Answer (score 0):

these are my steps to create custom Service

1- create interface

```
    public interface IProductService
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetAllProducts();
    string GetProduct(int? id);
}
```

2- create service

```
 public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return new[] { "Table", "Chair", "Desk", "Computer" };
        }

        // [Route("product/{id?}")]
        //https://localhost:44326/Umbraco/AwesomeProducts/Products/GetProduct?id=5
        public string GetProduct(int? id)
        {
            if (id is not null)
            {
                return $"Monitor model {id}";
            }
            return "Base model Monitor";
        }
    }
```

3- create controller

[PluginController("AwesomeProducts")]
public class ProductsController : UmbracoApiController
{
private readonly IProductService _productService;
public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
{
_productService = productService;
}
public IEnumerable GetAllProducts()
{
return _productService.GetAllProducts();
}

```
// [Route("product/{id?}")]
//https://localhost:44326/Umbraco/AwesomeProducts/Products/GetProduct?id=5
public string GetProduct(int? id)
{
  return _productService.GetProduct(id);
}
```

}

4- create extenstion

```
   public static class UmbracoBuilderServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IUmbracoBuilder AddCustomServices(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomNewsArticleService, CustomNewsArticleService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductService>();

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

5- modify startup

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddUmbraco(_env, _config)
                .AddBackOffice()
                .AddWebsite()
                .AddComposers()
                // Register all Delivery API dependencies
                .AddDeliveryApi()
                .AddCustomServices()
                .Build();

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(
        Constants.JsonOptionsNames.DeliveryApi,
        options =>
        {
            // set the maximum allowed depth of
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 200;
        });
        }
```

6- to call API
//https://localhost:44326/Umbraco/AwesomeProducts/Products/GetProduct?id=5

7- to call from razor page

```
@inject IProductService productService

    @{
    Layout = "master.cshtml";
    bool isPageProtected = PublicAccessService.IsProtected(Model.Path);
    var prodList = productService.GetAllProducts();

}
@if (isPageProtected)
{
        <h1>Secret Page - shhshshsh!</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1> Get Data From Controller</h1>
    <ul>
       
    @foreach (var item in prodList)
    {
       <li>@item</li> 
    }
    </ul>
}
```